How to turn off an Apple Watch after it was reset?
I had an Apple Watch 7 and I recently upgraded to a newer model. I then reset the 7, which made it go to the initial pairing screen. I want to reset it so I don't want to pair it with my phone again. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible to turn it off. If I press the side button for 2 seconds, I see the following screen. There's a power icon in the top-right corner but it doesn't work no matter if I tap, hold it, try to swipe it, etc.

If I hold the wide button for ~10 seconds, the Watch will reboot into pairing mode again, but I still can't turn it off. I ended up putting it away into a box and just letting the battery drain over time, but is there a way to actually turn it off?
